# How to avoid repeating code while creating classes in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to designing classes in Python. Assume that we have a small pandas dataframe, `df`. I want to write a few methods for this class which accepts this dataframe. In most methods, I want to work with a subset of just 2 columns and 2 rows. Assume that given the column numbers, the row numbers could be determined. Each method will use this subset. I ended up re-writing the sub-setting code for each method, which I am sure is redundant. How do I avoid this?

```
class Summary(object):
    def __init__(self,summary_df):
        self.summary = summary_df
        #look_up_table={dict created}

    def performance(self,col1,col2):
        self.col1 = col1
        self.col2 = col2
        self.row1 = look_up_table[self.col1]
        self.row2 = look_up_table[self.col2]

        self.subset = self.summary.loc[[self.row1,self.row2]][[self.col1,self.col2]]
        plt.plot(self.subset.iloc[0],self.subset.iloc[1],'--o')

        plt.xlabel(self.row1)
        plt.ylabel(self.row2)
        plt.show()

    def get_slope(self,col1,col2):
        self.col1 = col1
        self.col2 = col2
        self.row1 = look_up_table[self.col1]
        self.row2 = look_up_table[self.col2]

        self.subset = self.summary.loc[[self.row1,self.row2]][[self.col1,self.col2]]
        # code for calculating slope
        return slope

    def other_methods(self,col1,col2,col3)
```

I would like to avoid stating the column numbers when instantiating this class, if possible. Also, `def other_methods` may need more than 2 columns anyway, so limiting the data only to two columns may not efficient, I think.
Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: In `self.col1 = col1` is there any reason why you are saving local variables `col1` and `col2` on the object instance?

Comment: I thought that adding `self` as done in `self.col1=col1` was necessary so that the value of `col` could be used by methods in any instance of the class. Is that not right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. In fact, that's what I wanted to know. If you want to keep the latest col1 and col2 for further reference in other methods, I'll need to update my answer.

Comment: ...except not by "any instance" only the instance of the class you set them on. If you want them for all instances, you need to use class variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common portion of this code is to take column identifiers and turn them into row plus subset references. Since you want to keep these calculated values on the object, set them in a single helper function.

```
class Summary(object):

    def __init__(self,summary_df):
        self.summary = summary_df
        #look_up_table={dict created}

    def _update_for_columns(self, col1, col2):
        """Given col1 and col2, update self with new values for
        col1, col2, row1, row2 and subset"""
        self.col1 = col1
        self.col2 = col2
        self.row1 = look_up_table[self.col1]
        self.row2 = look_up_table[self.col2]
        self.subset = self.summary.loc[[self.row1,self.row2]][[self.col1,self.col2]]

    def performance(self,col1,col2):
        self._update_for_columns(col1, col2)
        plt.plot(self.subset.iloc[0], self.subset.iloc[1],'--o')
        plt.xlabel(self.row1)
        plt.ylabel(self.row2)
        plt.show()

    def get_slope(self,col1,col2):
        self._update_for_columns(col1, col2)
        # code for calculating slope
        return slope

    def other_methods(self,col1,col2,col3)
```

Better yet, since multiple methods want to use the same calculated values, they shouldn't also be setting the values. That results in needless recalculations. Have the caller update them before making any calls.

```
class Summary(object):

    def __init__(self,summary_df):
        self.summary = summary_df
        #look_up_table={dict created}

    def update_for_columns(self, col1, col2):
        """Update for new columns before calling performance, et al."""
        self.col1 = col1
        self.col2 = col2
        self.row1 = look_up_table[self.col1]
        self.row2 = look_up_table[self.col2]
        self.subset = self.summary.loc[[self.row1,self.row2]][[self.col1,self.col2]]


    def performance(self):
        plt.plot(self.subset.iloc[0], self.subset.iloc[1],'--o')
        plt.xlabel(self.row1)
        plt.ylabel(self.row2)
        plt.show()

    def get_slope(self):
        # code for calculating slope
        return slope

    def other_methods(self,col1,col2,col3)
```

And even better, put the methods that use columns into their own class so that you don't risk having two parts of your code think they are operating on the same thing.

```
class Summary(object):

    def __init__(self,summary_df):
        self.summary = summary_df
        #look_up_table={dict created}

    def get_summary_cols(self, col1, col2):
        return SummaryCols(self, col1, col2)

class SummaryCols(object):

    def __init__(self, summary, col1, col2):
        self.summary = summary # assuming you need stuff from summary...
        self.col1 = col1
        self.col2 = col2
        self.row1 = look_up_table[self.col1]
        self.row2 = look_up_table[self.col2]
        self.subset = self.summary.loc[[self.row1,self.row2]][[self.col1,self.col2]]

    def performance(self):
        plt.plot(self.subset.iloc[0], self.subset.iloc[1],'--o')
        plt.xlabel(self.row1)
        plt.ylabel(self.row2)
        plt.show()

    def get_slope(self):
        # code for calculating slope
        return slope

    def other_methods(self,col1,col2,col3)
```

Comment: What's the difference between the first and second code, other than the method name beginning with `_` in the first one?

Comment: In the second example, `performance` (and etc...) no longer takes `col1` and `col2` parameters. The caller must call `update_for_columns` before making the call. You said that you want `col1` and `col2` to be usable in multiple methods. Suppose someone calls `get_slope('foo', 'bar')` and then `performance('foo', 'bar')`. That should needlessly recalculate `row1`, 'row2' and `subset` (in that case, what was the point of remembering them?!). These methods shouldn't both want to use existing data and set new data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish since I'm not familiar with the underlying data so feel free to dismiss my answer if it's not helpful.

You could place the 'subsetting' portion of the code in the `__init__` so that when you instantiate the class the data transformations that are common throughout the methods are done at the beginning and in one place.

For example:

```
class Summary(object):
    def __init__(self,summary_df, col1, col2):
        self.summary = summary_df
        #look_up_table={dict created}

        self.col1 = col1
        self.col2 = col2
        self.row1 = look_up_table[self.col1]
        self.row2 = look_up_table[self.col2]

        self.subset = self.summary.loc[[self.row1,self.row2]][[self.col1,self.col2]]

    def performance(self):
        plt.plot(self.subset.iloc[0],self.subset.iloc[1],'--o')

        plt.xlabel(self.row1)
        plt.ylabel(self.row2)
        plt.show()

    def get_slope(self):
        # code for calculating slope
        return slope

    def other_methods(self,col1,col2,col3)
        # code for other stuff
```

Using `self` establishes a reference to the object to be used in the class.

**edit**: More examples

Assuming you're using pandas, you can pass the entire dataframe (or a relevant subset of it) to the class:

```
class Summary(object):
    def __init__(self, summary_df, data_df):
        self.summary = summary_df
        #look_up_table = {dict created}

        self.data_df = data_df

    # If it'll always be two columns
    def subset_df(self, some_col, another_col):
        # takes a vertical slice of the original df
        self.col1 = self.data_df[some_col]
        self.col2 = self.data_df[another_col]

        self.row1 = look_up_table[self.col1]
        self.row2 = look_up_table[self.col2]

        self.subset = self.summary.loc[[self.row1,self.row2]][[self.col1,self.col2]]
```

Now you can call it with:

```
do_summary = Summary(my_summary_df, my_data_df)
do_summary.subset_df('column_name1', 'column_name2')
print(do_summary.subset)
```

Comment: Putting the subsetting portion of the code in the `__init__` method would  mean that I won't be able to use other parts of the data - such as col3 and other columns, rows, right? Also, we do not know which two columns the user may be interested in working on, at the time of designing the class. Am I right?

Comment: If you want to reference other parts of the dataframe then why don't you have the class accept the dataframe and you can have parameters reference it directly.  I'll edit the answer with an example.